# Environment variables returning blank even though Maven build is happening fine

Tags: java, scala, maven, java-home

I'm using Maven as a build tool for Scala code. I'm able to build the Scala objects fine using maven. However when I echo `$M2_HOME` ,`$M2`,`$JAVA_HOME`, everything is returning blank. While this is a sign that these environment variables are not set properly, they are not causing any issues, which to me sounded a bit surprising. Can you please let me know what I'm missing here. I'm running Ubuntu 15.04 and included the below output if needed.

```
~$java -version
 openjdk version "1.8.0_45-internal"
 OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_45-internal-b14)
 OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.45-b02, mixed mode)

~$mvn -version
 Apache Maven 3.0.5
 Maven home: /usr/share/maven
 Java version: 1.8.0_45-internal, vendor: Oracle Corporation
 Java home: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre
 Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
 OS name: "linux", version: "3.19.0-58-generic", arch: "amd64",family: "unix"
```

This is the first time I'm using Java, Maven and Scala so kindly excuse my ignorance.

Comment: If `java` and `mvn` executables are present in your path, these variables are really not necessary to run the commands you show. But it is a good idea to set them since other tools (or even maven plugins) could depend on them.

Comment: Anyway, why are you using Maven to build scala code instead of [sbt](http://www.scala-sbt.org/)?

Comment: Not just these commands, I'm able to do `mvn compile' as well. My team uses maven so I started with that too.

Comment: By "these commands" I meant `java` and `mvn`. ;-)

Comment: Oh haha fine. Thanks for the info btw.

Comment: It is a good idea to set these variables to keep your local environment consistent with what your team is using or even with other tools you are using. But, since the commands are already at your path, they are not a hard requirement.